# How do you get chosen.js to use javascript generated cloned content?

Tags: javascript, clone, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.js version 1.8.7
I am able to clone the content of a div to another div with all of the data and events using clone(true).I have changed all of the ID's to have a new ID on the cloned items.
The problem is when I select a javascript generated select list, it activates the original select list and not itself.

I have tried cloning without all of the data and events by using clone(). It clones but it doesn't allow the newly generated `<select>` to drop-down at all.
I have removed chosen.js and the clone(true) copies everything and each `<select>` list works individually but there is no filter capability.

```
<form method="post" name="add_items">

<div class="clone-test" id="cloned">
<select id="items1" name="contract_item[]" class="form-control chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose a item...">
<option value="0">Select a Item</option>
<option value="1">Car 1</option>
<option value="2">Car 2</option>
<option value="3">Car 3</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="new_items"></div>


</form>

<input type="button" onclick="clone_div()" name="add" value="Add Another Item" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_select">


<script type="text/javascript">
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $("#cloned").length;

function clone_div(){
    $("#cloned").clone(true)
        .appendTo("#new_items")
        .attr("id", "cloned" +  cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
cloneIndex++;

$("#new_items").html(html);
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
}

</script>
```

I expect to have each individual `<select>` list to work independently having each list with filter capability using chosen.js. What I am getting is having the original select list activate no matter which javascript generated `<select>` list I choose.

Comment: I've added the code to JSFiddle for anyone to take a look at.
https://jsfiddle.net/Bigeloj/7h63xvkj/